# Is there a way to run MacOS software on linux?

Tags: linux, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS X as guest on VirtualBox with Ubuntu Host?](https://superuser.com/questions/98179/mac-os-x-as-guest-on-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-host)

**Note: This differs from previous Mac-on-linux/windows questions because:**

1. I don't mind buying the software if I can install it somehow,
2. I'm asking about virtualization, not emulation.

---

Is there any way to run OSX programs on my linux machine? I'm thinking something like running virtualbox with an OSX install on it, which works great for Windows programs.

If it's not possible, why not? (Perhaps virtualbox can't pretend to be the Mac hardware, or there is some kind of licence violation).

Comment: Still seems a dupe to me: "Mac OSX as guest on virtual box with Ubuntu Host?" at http://superuser.com/questions/98179/mac-osx-as-guest-on-virtual-box-with-ubuntu-host

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main problem is Apple, who own the rights to Mac OS X, will not license it to run on anything but Mac hardware. So running Mac OS X on Virtualbox etc. would be illegal (assuming such license restrictions are valid in your jurisdiction, but that's a legal question).

From a technical point of view, the versions that install on generic PCs (I've heard they exist) will probably also install in Virtualbox. There are (illegal) Virtualbox images for Mac OS X on the 'net.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier (not to mention legal) to do it other other way around, i.e. run Mac OS X on legitimate Apple hardware and then run Linux in a VM under Mac OS X using Parallels or VMware Fusion.