# How to install Mac OS X Leopard within VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, osx-leopard

I have the latest version of VirtualBox and a genuine copy of Mac OS X Leopard in the original installation disk that came with my laptop. My desktop is a Windows 7 x64 so I want to use VirtualBox to install Leopard in it.

Problem is when I create a new virtual machine (by selecting Mac OS X as the OS type) and then when I start the machine with my Leopard cd in the drive I get the following message:

> "Press ESC in 4 seconds to
>   skip startup.nsh, any other key to
>   continue"

This appears inside a command prompt like window. If I press ESC before the 4 seconds is up nothing happens I just stay in the window. If I press any key, same deal, I just stay in the window and whatever key I press is merely typed on the black screen.

Does anyone know how to install MAC OSX from a physical cd in VirtualBox?

P.S. The prompt on the screen is

> Shell>

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/56564/mac-os-x-for-virtualbox http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc **AND** http://superuser.com/questions/98179/mac-os-x-as-guest-on-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently VirtualBox only supports OS X server 10.5 and 10.6. The version of Leopard you have is not a valid guest OS.